# complete dropdownlist with stored procedure, using viewmodel

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, viewmodel, procedure

good day and thanks for your time.
I have been trying to look for answers for my problem but I could not get any.
I am working with mvc dropdownlists.. I have a database with a stored procedure

```
Select Id, Name from table
```

I also have a controller like this

```
 ` testEntities db = new testEntities();
        var result = db.read().ToList();
        return View();`
```

Please, help me because I would need to use a viewmodel and use that viewmodel in the view in order to get a strong typed view.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You haven't provided any details of the language you're using, the database or any relevant frameworks. Your tags are just for general concepts. As a result it's unlikely anybody with enough knowledge will find your question and be able to help answer it.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new here..your feed back will help me to improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define your viewmodel:

```
public class TestEntityViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, create this viewmodel in your controller, like this:

```
testEntities db = new testEntities();
var result = db.read().ToList();
var viewModels = result.Select(x => new SelectListItem(){ Value = x.Id, Text = x.Name);
return View(viewModels);
```

At last, you can populate it in your view, like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

<select>
foreach (var item on Model)
{
    <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
}
</select>
```

You can also use built-in select tag helper, or DropDownList html helper, this is the simplest example.